try to disable hover effect during nivation between TabBar Tabs in .NET MAUI
I tried a lot to hide/disable Hover effect as the below form app but I can't get the item that has this effect
the issue when I click on any Menu tap makes a short hover circle and it affects UI Badly
XAML Code :
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell 
    x:Class="MauiApp1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Views.Main"
    xmlns:auth_folder="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Views.Auth"
    Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="White" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True" Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="White"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Shell.TabBarDisabledColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
    Shell.UnselectedColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.ForegroundColor="White" 
    Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
    Shell.TitleColor="White"  
    Shell.NavBarHasShadow="False" >

    <Shell.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar">
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarCurrentBackgroundColor" Value="Orange" /> // New API function
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </Shell.Resources>


    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate auth_folder:GetStarted}" Route="GetStarted"/>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate auth_folder:LoginForm}" Route="LoginForm"/>

    <TabBar>
        
        <Tab Icon="b_home.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Home}" Route="Home" PropertyChanged="ShellContent_PropertyChanged"
                           Icon="{OnPlatform 'b_home.png', iOS='b_home.png' }" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Icon="b_persona.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Profile}" Route="About" PropertyChanged="ShellContent_PropertyChanged"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'b_persona.png', iOS='b_persona.png'}" />
        </Tab>
   
        <Tab Icon="b_tel.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Red365}" Route="Red365" PropertyChanged="ShellContent_PropertyChanged"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'b_tel.png', iOS='b_tel.png'}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>


I`m still searching for a UI trigger to disable the hover effect


And here is the effect, you can check it.

You can also see this doc: Page handlers to learn about Handler of Shell.

You can disable it by modifying ItemBackground of BottomNavigationView:
namespace MauiApp2.Platforms.Android
{
    public partial class ShellHandlerEx : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new CustomSheladdlBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
                (this, shellItem.CurrentItem);
        }
    }
}

namespace MauiApp2.Platforms.Android
{
    public class CustomSheladdlBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem)
    : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(shellContext, shellItem)
    {
        private readonly IShellContext shellContext = shellContext;
        public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
            if (Shell.GetTabBarIsVisible(shellContext.Shell.CurrentPage))
            {
                var backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
                backgroundDrawable.SetColor(appearance.EffectiveTabBarBackgroundColor.ToPlatform());
 
                bottomView.ItemBackground = backgroundDrawable;
            }
        }
    }
}

Finally register it in MauiProgram.cs
#if ANDROID
using MauiApp2.Platforms.Android;
#endif


var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
    ....
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
#if ANDROID
         handlers.AddHandler<Shell, ShellHandlerEx>();
#endif
    });

